# Aspose : set custom properties to a sheet using aspose jar

Tags: java, excel, worksheet, aspose-cells

How to Write custom properties to a sheet in workbook using aspose - cells  -7

```
CustomPropertyCollection custom = customProp.getCustomProperties();
```

Here's a code snippet to begin with

Answer (score 0):

See the following sample code using [Aspose.Cells](https://products.aspose.com/cells/java) for Java to accomplish the task for your reference:

e.g.

**Sample code:**

```
// Open an Excel file
Workbook workbook = new Workbook("Book1.xlsx");
 
// Retrieve a list of all custom document properties of the Excel file
CustomDocumentPropertyCollection customProperties = workbook.getWorksheets().getCustomDocumentProperties();
 
// Adding a custom document property to the Excel file
DocumentProperty publisher = customProperties.add("Publisher", "Aspose");

// Save the file
workbook.save("out1.xlsx", SaveFormat.XLSX);
```

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.